# Change in source code

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I have two question

1. I have done some changes in C-backend of LLVM-2.9 source code. Now what I wanna is how can I reflect these changes in build folder?
2. What does `make update` do ? When I run this command this is what happen in my terminal.

   ```
   arpit@arpit-HP-dx2480-MT-KL969AV:~/llvm1/build$ sudo make update
   svn  update /home/arpit/llvm1/llvm
   Skipped '/home/arpit/llvm1/llvm'
   svn: warning: '/home/arpit/llvm1/llvm' is not a working copy
   Skipped '.'
   ```

Comment: 1. Make check what has changed and redoes anything that depends on it. It's the reason for it's existence. So just re-run `make` exactly as when you've initially built it.

Comment: 2. Apparently runs `svn update`. Since you didn't check out from subversion, it is of no use to you (I suppose it runs svn update across all the modules that are checked out from separate repositories).

Comment: 3. Version 2.9 is _ancient_. Shouldn't you be working on current version (3.3 or even development version).

Comment: @JanHudec I rerun `make` command as you said but the change was not reflected

Answer (score 0):

`make update` updates LLVM and Clang and other sub-projects, so it's not what you need. What you do need is just `make` in the build folder. If any of the source files changed, `make` is supposed to pick it up and re-build the relevant files.

Maybe the specific changes you made are not picked up by `make`, have you added a new file? You can always try to build everything anew (e.g. `make -B`) and see if the change is included.

Comment: no I have not added a new file just few changes in existing file.